# Autostart download

Tags: downloads, autostart

How to autostart downloads when ubuntu starts. I know how to autostart torrent clients like transmission or deluge client during startup. But the application only starts, it doesnt start downloading. Please mention any torrent client or download managers that resume downloads automatically when Ubuntu starts, assuming it is connected to internet. If such apps don't exist, please mention some mechanism by which I can accomplish the task.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareUpdates

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Deluge and transmission are torrent clients, not download managers.  It depends on the exact torrent client how to start downloading immediately after application start-up and requires an always-on Internet connection (like a LAN or WiFi connection or an autoconnect modem connection)  **Please rephrase your question so it becomes more clear what you're trying to accomplish.**

Comment: What method are you using to run the apps on startup?

Comment: I am using the 'startup applications' found in Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay Fabby, do you know any torrent client or download managers that resume downloads automatically when Ubuntu starts, assuming it is connected to internet.

Comment: @Firoz I think that UTorrent will do this on Windows, maybe try it on Ubuntu.

Comment: `qbittorrent` can start automatically, as well as its torrents.

Also this seems to be turning into an opinion based comment chain.

Comment: Transmission automatically resume pending tasks upon launch as long as the file is present on disk, there are free space on the device and you haven't stopped them manually. Be it downloading or seeding. If transmission is not resuming your torrents after relaunch, check the preferences for any conflicting option.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. I used to stop downloads and close all programs before shutting down. Just let it be and its fine. Thanks eridani for mentioning that.